# Adobe Flash Professional

Tags: adobe

дайте 32 битную рабочую версию компилятора Adobe Flash Professional, а то инсталятор выкидывает ошибку.[image: Error]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что с такими вопросами нужно обращаться в Adobe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вас интересует только компилятор без IDE, то он входит в состав пакета Apache Flex, который можно скачать с официального сайта: http://flex.apache.org/

Сама же интегрированная среда разработки Adobe Flash CC является платным продуктом и поддерживается компанией Adobe. Если Вы заплатили за программу, то все вопросы отправляйте в техподдержку этой компании. Если не заплатили, то опять же вопросы не к нашему сообществу, т.к. мы не занимается вопросами приобретения пиратского софта.

Comment: спасибо, удалил Adobe Flash Professional, интересы поменялись.